# Error when retrieving data to display. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, beautifulsoup

I have a small script that worked correctly when the code was all in one file (this detail is important). Now, i wanted to put the script in a Tabcontrol with an external file, so i put the script code in the external file `page1.py` which is opened by the Tabcontrol of the `main.py` file

Now I get this error:

```
item = df.iloc[selection[-1]]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

When do I get the error? The code is meant to display a list of all of a site's news headlines when i click on the `View Title`s button (this currently works correctly). I get the problem when i select a title line and click on the `View Content` button

Where is the problem in the code? The problem is in the `content` function of the `page1.py` file:

```
        def content(event=None): 
            selection = listbox_title.curselection()
            print('selection:', selection)

            if selection:
                item = df.iloc[selection[-1]]
                url = item['link']
```

To consider that the script, previously, correctly fine in a single file. The code is now the same, but used in a tabcontrol. If tried using `print(df)` it printed fine correctly.

**Main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

from page1 import Page1

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('480x720')
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')


nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

page1 = Page1(nb)

nb.add(page1, text='Tab1', compound='left')

root.mainloop()
```

The problem is in the `content` function of the page1.py file.

**Page.py**

```
import tkinter as tk   
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import requests
import requests_cache 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
import json
from dateutil import parser
import datetime
import locale

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        def get(place):
            headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
            }

            results = []
            response = requests.get(f'https://www.example.com/{place}/', headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

            ####################################################################################
            #Cover
            cover_news = soup.find('div', {'class':'box pp'})
            link = cover_news.find('a', href=True)['href']
            coverNewsResponse = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
            coverSoup = BeautifulSoup(coverNewsResponse.content, 'html.parser')
            jsonStr = str(coverSoup.find('script'))
            jsonStr = re.search('({.*})', jsonStr).group(1)
            jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
            
            timePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%H:%M")
            datePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            title = jsonData['headline']
            news = f" {timePublished} {place.upper()}, {title} (TMW)"
            results.append( [datePublished, timePublished, place, title, news, link] )



            ####################################################################################
            # Side panel
            side_news = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'box small'})
            for each in side_news:
                try:
                    link = each.find('a', href=True)['href']
                    sideNewsResponse = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
                    sideSoup = BeautifulSoup(sideNewsResponse.content, 'html.parser')
                    jsonStr = str(sideSoup.find('script'))
                    jsonStr = re.search('({.*})', jsonStr).group(1)
                    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
                    
                    timePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%H:%M")
                    datePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    title = jsonData['headline']
                    news = f" {timePublished} {place.upper()}, {title} (TMW)"
                    results.append( [datePublished, timePublished, place, title, news, link] )
                except:
                    print("Error")
                    continue
                    
                
            ####################################################################################
            #Center
            news = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "tcc-list-news"})

            for each in news:
                for div in each.find_all("div"):
                    timePublished  = div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'hh serif'}).text
                    datePublished = div.find_previous('div', {'class':'tcc-border upper date'})
                    
                    if datePublished:
                        if datePublished.text in ['Ieri']:
                            yesterday = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
                            datePublished = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                        else:
                            locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
                            currentYear = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y")
                            dateStr = datePublished.text
                            dateStr = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr + ' ' + currentYear, '%A %d %B %Y')
                            datePublished = dateStr.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    else:
                        datePublished = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    
                    title = " ".join(span.text for span in div.select("a > span"))
                    news = f" {timePublished} {place.upper()}, {title} (TMW)" #rigo della notizia
                    link  = div.find('a')['href']
                    results.append( [datePublished, timePublished, place, title, news, link] )

            return results


        ####################################################################################
        #Titles
        def all_titles():
            global df

            allnews = []
            new = []

            for place in ['name1', 'name2']:         
                results = get(place)
                allnews += results
                text_download.insert('end', f"search: {place}\nfound: {len(results)}\n")


                for place in ['name1']:
                    for sublist in allnews:
                        for item in sublist:
                            if "Name1" in item:
                                new += [sublist]


                for place in ['name2']:
                    for sublist in allnews:
                        for item in sublist:
                            if "Name2" in item:
                                new += [sublist]


            df = pd.DataFrame(new, columns=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title', 'news', 'link'])
            df = df.sort_values(by=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title'], ascending=[False, False, True, True])
            df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title'])
            df = df.reset_index(drop=True)


            listbox_title.delete('0', 'end')


            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                #Name1
                for place in ['name1'] 
                     if "Example" in row['news']:          
                         listbox_title.insert('end', row['news'])


        def content(event=None): 
            selection = listbox_title.curselection()
            print('selection:', selection)

            if selection:
                item = df.iloc[selection[-1]]
                url = item['link']

                headers = {
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
                }

                session = requests_cache.CachedSession('titles')
                response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

                content_download = "\n".join(item.get_text() for item in soup.select("div.text.mbottom"))

                text_download.delete('1.0', 'end')
                text_download.insert('end', content_download)


        df = None


        #GUI
        frame_title = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_title.pack(fill='both', expand=True, pady=5, padx=5)

        listbox_title = tk.Listbox(frame_title, selectbackground="#960000", selectforeground="white", bg="white")
        listbox_title.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

        scrollbar_title = tk.Scrollbar(frame_title)
        scrollbar_title.pack(side='left', fill='y')

        scrollbar_title['command'] = listbox_title.yview
        listbox_title.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_title.set)

        listbox_title.bind('<Double-Button-1>', content)

        text_download = ScrolledText(self, bg="white")
        text_download.pack(fill='both', expand=True, pady=0, padx=5)

        buttons_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        buttons_frame.pack(fill='x')

        button1 = tk.Button(buttons_frame, text="View Titles", command=all_titles) 
        button1.pack(side='left', pady=5, padx=5)

        button2 = tk.Button(buttons_frame, text="View Content", command=content)  
        button2.pack(side='left', pady=5, padx=(0,5))
```

Comment: Have you wondered why df == None ?

Comment: @DarkKnight Yes, but I didn't understand. I also tried using print(df) and it printed fine correctly

Comment: @DarkKnight As explained in the question, the script worked fine when it was in a single file. So before df was not None. The code is the same. So the problem is not my script code, but it will be something related to the tabcontrol, class, self or function of the tabcontrol

Comment: @jezrael No, I haven't tried it yet. What should change if I remove df = None? Why should df = None be a problem? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use instance variable `self.df` instead of global variable `df` since it is inside a class?  Actually `df` inside nested function `content()` refers to the local variable `df` defined inside `__init__()`, but `df` inside nested function `all_titles()` is declared as global variable, so the two functions refer to different `df`.

Comment: @acw1668 Could you show me an answer with written what should i change please? self.df should I add it to the dfs of both functions ("content" and "all titles")? self.df should I add it only in certain points or to all df? do i have to delete global? I would be grateful if you could show me with an answer, thanks

Comment: You can try changing `global df` to `nonlocal df` inside `all_titles()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, with nonlocal df works correctly. Thank you. Before you answered me, I just tried deleting df = None (as suggested by jezrael in a comment and then deleted) and it worked correctly. Would the best solution be to use nonlocal df? Or NOT to use nonlocal df (keep using global df) and only delete df = None? Thank you

Comment: My suggestion is to change all `df` to instance variable `self.df`.

Comment: @acw1668 Could you show me the solution with the full code please? I'd be happy to accept your answer as a solution. Thank you

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As I said in my last comment, just replace all occurrences of `df` by `self.df`.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried to add self.df to all df, but maybe i added self. even to some df where it was not needed. Can you show me the full code of how i can add self.ds please? I will accept your answer as a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used class in your code, I would suggest to use instance variable instead of global variable:

```py
class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        ...
        def all_titles():
            #global df   # don't use global
            ...
            df = pd.DataFrame(new, columns=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title', 'news', 'link'])
            df = df.sort_values(by=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title'], ascending=[False, False, True, True])
            df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title'])
            self.df = df.reset_index(drop=True)  ### df to self.df in LHS

            listbox_title.delete('0', 'end')

            for index, row in self.df.iterrows():   ### df to self.df
                #Name1
                for place in ['name1']:
                     if "Example" in row['news']:
                         listbox_title.insert('end', row['news'])

        def content(event=None):
            selection = listbox_title.curselection()
            print('selection:', selection)

            if selection:
                item = self.df.iloc[selection[-1]]  ### df to self.df
                url = item['link']

                headers = {
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
                }

                session = requests_cache.CachedSession('titles')
                response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

                content_download = "\n".join(item.get_text() for item in soup.select("div.text.mbottom"))

                text_download.delete('1.0', 'end')
                text_download.insert('end', content_download)


        self.df = None  ### df to self.df

        ...
```

Comment: Thank you. It works properly. With classes I'm not very experienced, so I would like to ask you a question please, I hope you will answer: why didn't you add df as a parameter in def __init__ and then why didn't you write self.df = df inside def __init__? Thank you

Comment: You are the designer of class `Page1`, so what arguments are used in `Page1.__init__()` depends on your application design.  My solution is just based on your posted code and I don't know your overall application design.

Comment: Ah OK. So I speak in general, without thinking about my code. It's just a little curiosity. In general, should only design arguments go into Page1.__init__()? For example combobox1 and then self.combobox1 = combobox1? Should code that isn't about design, but about a simple function, be written in Page1.__init__()?